# Displaying maps offline, inside mobile hybrid app

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, web-mapping, software-recommendations, mobile

I want to develop a mobile hybrid application to run on both Android & iPhone devices in which i want to display my own map data. I have the SHP files with the data I need. I have GeoServer and PostGIS for loading and serving the map data online. So far everything is fine.

My problem is that i still haven’t figure out the correct walkthrough for displaying the map data OFFLINE.  Although I have read many answers here in this website, none of them seems to solve (as per my understanding my issue).

The goal is to display points of interrest on map. offline.
Some Points of interrest doesnt have address.Just Lon/Lat.
I want to cover these requirements:

1. How to offer the map data & the content offline to users device?
2. How to offer to user routing options to navigate him to the destination from current location?
3. How to add content data from a WordPress CMS, inside the app? (via JSON?GeoJSON?GeoRSS?)

Have been searching and looking many Tile services and many approaches to achieve the requirements, but still havent figure out the correct combination.

For the development of app I've been using PhoneGap XDK, Eclipse ADT. And for displaying the maps on mobile devices I'm using OpenLayers mobile.

Answer (score 3):

Considering that you are not willing to move to an [Esri](http://www.esri.com) solution (using their [mobile APIs](http://developers.arcgis.com/en/)) I would recommend [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) since it'll be possible to use it with Phonegap.

Take a look at this article (with sample code and valuable commentaries): http://geospatialscott.blogspot.com.br/2012/04/phonegap-leaflet-tilemill-offline.html

A quick walkthrough your questions:

- How to offer the map data & the content offline to users device

  - Keep data using a mobile friendly/compatible format (like sqlite or json) for offline access (you should write your custom export/import app if not using a existent COTS solution)
  - Use a client-side rendering solution (like Leafleft (do not forget their plugins) or even [D3](http://d3js.org))
- How to offer to user routing options to navigate him to the destination from current location

  - Much harder. I don't know any offline routing library based on Json and Javascript, maybe you will have to implement your own engine - considering performance and optimization not a very easy task (COTS solution like ESRI does support it out of the box).
  - Most solutions actually do a round-trip to the server and bring the processed route to the device. If absolutely disconnected routing capabilities are not necessary this is the easiest path.
- How to add content data from a WordPress CMS, inside the app?

  - I'm not sure what you mean by this point. RSS, JSON and simple HTML caching are possible ways.

*Disclaimer: I'm not an Esri employee but I do work with Esri solutions, that's why I'm using it to give you options. Of course you could consider other commercial solutions to this scenario.*